# How to Mock send method in MessageChannel of SpringBoot in Wiremock Integration Testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, integration-testing, wiremock

I am using Spring Boot Java for my application. The application is sending some messages to Kafka using MessageChannel. Ex: this.messageChannel.send(message).

I would like to mock this message channel call in integration testing so that messages are not sent to Kafka. Currently using Wiremock for Spring Integration Testing.

Please suggest me the ways to mock the MessageChannel send method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Kafka MessageChannel for integration tests, then use `spring-kafka-test`'s Embedded Kafka server...

Mocks typically aren't used for integration tests. Perhaps you meant fakes?

In which case you need to create your own class that `implements MessageChannel` and overwrite the `send` function with the behavior you're expecting, then pass that to the constructor of the class that you are referring to as `this`  in your question.

Alternatively, sounds like you want [`spring-integration-http`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http) if you are using WireMock and intend to `send` messages to an HTTP endpoint rather than Kafka.